# form authentication info in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm using asp.net mvc form authentication and storing thro' setauthcokkie();

how can i get the logged in user information in my index or any controller.

Answer (score 2):

Each controller has  User property from which you can get the logged in user information.  The same is true for your views -- ViewPage has a User property.